# count elements inside id<NSFastEnumeration>

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, enumeration

I have an `id<NSFastEnumeration>` object. I want to count the elements inside the object. How can that be achieved?

The only method NSFastEnumeration implements is:

```
- (NSUInteger)countByEnumeratingWithState:(NSFastEnumerationState *)state objects:(id *)stackbuf count:(NSUInteger)len
```

This method returns the count I am looking for, but as I do not want to really enumerate the objects I wonder, what I could safely pass in as arguments. Would it be OK to just pass nil,nil,0? If not, what should I pass?

The Background:

I want to create an NSArray of the return values of a function, which I want to call with every element in the given collection. I want an Array of the results of enumerating a collection with a function.

```
id<NSFastEnumeration> enumeratable = someObject;
NSMutableArray* results = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:(#Fill in count here#)];
for (id object in enumeratable) {
    [results addObject:callFunctionOnObject(object)];
}
```

AS you can see I only need the count to optimize Array initialization. I am pretty aware that I could use `NSMutableArray* results = [NSMutableArray array];` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to get the length from an NSFastEnumeration is to loop through it.

```
int count = 0;
for (id x in enumerator)
  ++ count;
return count;
```

Of course this means the `enumerator` will be exhausted and you can't loop it again.

Also, the capacity is just a hint. There's little benefit in setting it.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I know the capacity is only a hint, but then I got curious and wanted to know. I will stick with `NSMutableArray* results = [NSMutableArray array];` then.

Comment: *Of course this means the enumerator will be exhausted and you can't loop it again.*  Does it?  I can't find anywhere in the docs where it says that is true.

Comment: @Jeremy: Take a look at NSEnumerator, which adopts NSFastEnumeration.

Comment: TM: I did check out the docs of NSEnumerator but it doesn't say that using `for(... in ...)` on an enumerator exhausts the enumerator.  I have, however tried it and found that it is true.